# Why are curly-braces needed for boolean variable in java eclipse?

Tags: java, boolean, curly-braces

I have no idea why this code makes an error.

```
public class TestIf {

    boolean money = true; // { <- This resolves the error.

    if (money) {
        System.out.println("Take a taxi");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Walk");
    }
// } <- This resolves error.
}
```

Is boolean not a variable, but is a kind of loop? I can't understand at all. Help me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `if-else` block needs to be in a method

Comment: The braces that resolve your error create an instance initializer for your code to be in.  Statements such (e.g. if/else) need to be in blocks, methods, or constructors.

Comment: Thanks man, I was soooo stupid.